# Saving Stata file with R while preserving labels

Tags: r, stata, r-haven

I have found a bug in the R `haven` package where `write_dta` drops some of the labels when reading it in Stata. I have [filed the bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/issues/435) in `haven` but I really need to find a work around until the bug is fixed. Below is the explanation.

Let's define a labelled double with only **one** tagged `NA` value.

```r
library(haven)
#> Warning: package 'haven' was built under R version 3.4.4

tst <-
  labelled(
    c(
      1:5,
      tagged_na("d")
    ),
    c(
      "Agree Strongly" = 1,
      "Agree" = 2,
      "Neither agree nor disagree" = 3,
      "Disagree" = 4,
      "Disagree strongly" = 5,
      "No answer" = tagged_na("d")
    )
  )

tst
#> <Labelled double>
#> [1]     1     2     3     4     5 NA(d)
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value                      label
#>      1             Agree Strongly
#>      2                      Agree
#>      3 Neither agree nor disagree
#>      4                   Disagree
#>      5          Disagree strongly
#>  NA(d)                  No answer

write_dta(data.frame(freehms = tst), "test.dta", version = 13)
```

If I load this in Stata and type `tab freehms`, all labels are correct:

[image: screen shot 2019-02-23 at 4 06 36 pm]

Now, if I take the code above and add another tagged `NA` value, then `write_dta` drops the last label for some reason:

```r
library(haven)
#> Warning: package 'haven' was built under R version 3.4.4

tst <-
  labelled(c(1:5,
             tagged_na('d'),
             ## Only added this
             tagged_na('c')
          ),
        c('Agree Strongly' = 1,
          'Agree' = 2,
          'Neither agree nor disagree' = 3,
          'Disagree' = 4,
          'Disagree strongly' = 5,
          'No answer' = tagged_na('d'),
            ## And this
          'Dont know' = tagged_na('c')
          )
        )

tst
#> <Labelled double>
#> [1]     1     2     3     4     5 NA(d) NA(c)
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value                      label
#>      1             Agree Strongly
#>      2                      Agree
#>      3 Neither agree nor disagree
#>      4                   Disagree
#>      5          Disagree strongly
#>  NA(d)                  No answer
#>  NA(c)                  Dont know

write_dta(data.frame(freehms = tst), "test.dta", version = 13)
```

[image: screen shot 2019-02-23 at 4 08 29 pm]

I have looked at the `write.dta` function from `foreign` but it doesn't seem to support Stata versions after version 11. Is there any other work around to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include missing option to also visualize summaries of the missing values as shown

```
tab freehms, mi
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but does not fix the problem. I'm not looking to see the missing values but as you can see from above, the label for the value 5 was dropped (which is not a missing value category)